# Apply a function references by string name in magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I have a data frame that contains a column with the name of a function I would like to apply to a partition of that data defined by a grouping. Here's a simple example of the set-up:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4))
df.with.method <- df %>% merge(y = data.frame(method = c("mean",   "median")))
```

what I want to do know is apply the method to each partition, like so:

```
df.with.method %>% group_by(method) %>%
    mutate(x.hat = eval(method)(x))
```

This doesn't work, however, returning a `Error: attempt to apply non-function` error. This does not work either:

```
df.with.method %>% group_by(method) %>%
    mutate(x.hat = eval(parse(text = method))(x))
```

However, this does work, which suggests the basic idea is OK:

```
df.with.method %>% group_by(method) %>%
    mutate(x.hat = eval(parse(text = "mean"))(x))
```

Comment: `get(unique(method))(x)` works supposing your method is of character class.

Comment: ... assuming that you merge it with `data.frame(method = c("mean", "median"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. Currently it's a `factor`, so the `get(unique(method))(x)` may not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the call and evaluate it with `call()` and `eval()` respectively. It's not pretty but it works, and be sure to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for `df.with.method`.

```
df.with.method %>% group_by(method) %>%
    mutate(x.hat = mapply(function(a, b) eval(call(a, b)), method, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  Note that we use `data_frame` rather than `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(x = c(1,2,3,4))
df.with.method <- df %>% merge(y = data_frame(method = c("mean", "median")))

df.with.method %>%
   group_by(method) %>%
   summarize(x = match.fun(method[1])(x)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

The `summarize` part could alternately be:

```
   summarize(x = do.call(method[1], list(x)))
```

If `df.with.method` must be as shown in question exactly, i.e. `method` is a factor, then replace `method` with `as.character(method)` in the `summarize` statement.